# Outlook 2010 crashes when replying to emails with digital signature

Tags: windows-8, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I have Outlook 2010 with an Exchange account. Recently I upgraded to Windows 8 and ever since, I have an issue where Outlook completely freezes and crashes when I reply to specific emails. These emails are always ones that contain someone else's digital signature. It should be noted that my account also has a digital signature installed (which I already tried reinstalling).

I have disabled add-ins and and tried running in safe mode but the same thing happens. I also tried recreating the profile but it didn't help. The one thing I found to fix the issue is to run Outlook as an administrator. When I do so, replying to the problem emails works. Instead of freezing, Outlook asks for my permission to use my digital signature. The problem with this fix is that Outlook Instant Search is disabled when running as administrator, so I can't use this fix.

Any ideas what I could do to resolve this, once and for all?

Comment: do you have the Office 2010 Sp2 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39667) installed? If not, install it and look if this fixes it.

Comment: i'll give it a shot and see